# Roothaan matrix equation equation orbital coefficients

Tags: quantum-chemistry

To go from the Hartree_Fock

$f\psi{_i}=\epsilon\psi{_i}$

to the  Roothaan equation

$FC=SC\epsilon$.

equation we expand the orbitals as

$\psi{_i}=\sum C_{\mu i}\phi_i$

But for Helium atom we have just one orbital function so the coefficient $C_{\mu i}$ should be a vector not a matrix. 
My question is  what is the interpretation of the matrix coefficient $C$ in the Roothaan equation  $FC=SC\epsilon$ for the helium atom since we've got just one spatial orbital function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\mathbf{C}$ matrix will always be $K\times K$, where $K$ is the size of the finite basis set you are using. That is to say, with a basis set of size $K$, you will produce exactly $K$ MOs. This means you will never wind up with $\mathbf{C}$ being a vector. In the [example](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1051495.pdf) you linked, they use a basis set of size 2, so they get 2 MOs for helium and thus the $\mathbf{C}$ matrix is $2\times 2$. While helium has only one occupied spatial orbital, it will have $K-1$ virtual orbitals depending the size of the basis set you use to solve the restricted Roothaan-Hall equations.

Comment: So  what you mean is that if $\mathbf{C}$ is  $2\times 2$ matrix, one column of the matrix will be the coefficients of the occupied spatial orbital(the one with smaller $\epsilon$ ) and the other coefficients of a virtual excited state ?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira exactly. The only way you wouldn't wind up with a $\mathbf{C}$ matrix per se is if you only used a single basis function, though you could obviously still treat it as a $1\times 1$ matrix.